# How to cache a query response with Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have a database that syncs completely every 2 hours. All data is dropped and populated from the main data source.

I have some queries coming from client app, that have the same response for the current 2-hours dataset. So, if 100 clients run their apps, I will have to run this query 100 times for each of them, even though they don't differ.

How do I avoid running this real query against my database every time, but just keep its response somewhere and return it instead?

I think I can run this query after each sync and save to its own table then return from it.

What are other options, probably provided by Postgres itself?

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like [redis](https://redis.io/) to store the result or your query in memory. It comes with many [clients](https://redis.io/clients). You can invalidate the result of this query when it's time to.

There are other memory caching like [memcache](https://memcached.org), easy to install & to use.

Note these are specific to postgres.